# Fit a object into interface dynamically

Tags: typescript

I would like to get a data from a `:any` object and insert it into the `:iInterface` in typescript

This example obj:

```
 name: "Gulherme",
 Query: "test",
 id: 2,
 namespace: "Test"
```

Insert and generate into this interface:

```
interface Test{
    name:string,
    id:number
}
```

The obj is dynamically loaded.

I did something like that but with no success.

```
var result:Test= obj as Test;
```

Expected result:

```
result = {
   name: "Gulherme",
   id: 2
}
```

The field from `obj` that doesn't match with the interface, can be deleted.

Comment: Casting does not change the shape of the object. That is, it only affects the type system (TypeScript), it does not have any effect on runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I made it a bit more dynamic so you can choose the keys you want.

```
// takes any object and keys of the specified generic.
function pick<T>(obj: any, ...keys: (keyof T)[]): Pick<T, typeof keys[number]> {
    // object into which the key-value pairs will be added
    let object: any = {};
    // loop over the passed object by transforming it into
    // an array of entries ([key, value]).
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, entry) => {
        const entryKey = entry[0] as keyof T;
        // only add the key-value pair of the passed object 
        // if it is in the specified keys.
        if (keys.includes(entryKey)) {
            acc[entryKey] = entry[1];
        }
        return acc;
    }, object);
}

pick<Test>(obj, "id", "name");
```

You could wrap this in another function if it's always those keys for the test object that you want - specifiying obj to then structurally conform to Test would make sense here, unless you want to randomly pass objects in and be fine with empty return (thanks @Juan Mendes):

```
function transformToTest(obj: Test) {
    return pick<Test>(obj, "id", "name");
}`
```

If you want to pass the keys as an array, change the signature of the function to look like this:

```
function pick<T>(obj: any, keys: (keyof T)[]): Pick<T, typeof keys[number]>
```

If the keys don't exist it will return an empty object.

Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUASDAQwFsBTALhgCIBxAVwBsALIgJ2PIBocBFa5gTzPJQi0djgCWAEwEAmUbkLCADnmCkKAFWFRRAXwDcmTGLBCmAMxVEYm6Bhz5iZaE2MBzA9klkw1AvGYGOoZm1GDAUGLgMIpiwADWADzqAHwAFAiIZHhgvGwwAHSFcUS8EGSpxbwgZtYAlADaALq1ZAAKsYnqeVC8ikTVMJUQ9T5+zI3Jdti0RLAZROFZOagY+jhMs9RMYDAA8kgLUPlEJi7C6Ui1+RsS1KqpqSrAeSdQTLy1qJNY2NigkLBXu8ANIlFZA3j1AAMjRgeAggxKA3UHk8NQqJQg+WMwFo1Ak5whoI+nx+vye9SJJVhaAh9QAjI1UUFfhsoFsdk8PDo8vNwrVAsFQuFIjs3tkIGYQCx1CAbFALpk4TlSetNttoh0klo0hk8uRJOwKA4iOQBZggph-hAQDN8rQQK5UjF4troLqkPrDfqTWbzdbbUR7Y7UuLIFKZXKtIragKgA)

Comment: This is amazing. how can i change to work with the call like it: console.log(pick<Test>(obj, ["id", "name"]));

Comment: to send as a array of accept parameter (name,id)

Comment: like this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUASDAQwFsBTALhgCIBxAVwBsALIgJ2PIBocBFa5gTzPJQi0djgCWAEwEAmUbkLCADnmCkKAFWFRRAXwDcmTGLBCmAMxVEYm6Bhz5iZaE2MBzA9klkw1AvGYGOoZm1GDAUGLgMIpiwADWADzqAHwAFAiIZHhgvGwwcUS8EGSpBbwgZtYAlADaALpVZAAKsYnqeVC8ikQV+YUQNT5+zHXJdti0RLAZROFZOagY+jhMU9RMYDAA8kizUAB0RCYuwulIVfurEtSqqakqwHlHUEy8VahjWNjYoJCwz68ANKFRYA3g1AAMdRgeAgfXKlXUHk8lVK-X2xmAtGoElOYOBb3eX2+Dxq+MK0LQYJqAEY6sigt9VlB1psHh4dHkZuEqoFgqFwpFNi9shAzCAWOoQDYoGdMjCckSVmsNtFWkktGkMnkauRJOwKA4iOQGnzML8ICBJvtaCBXKkYvENdAtUgdXqJAbyEaTVVeebwJbrbb7SLIOLJdKtHK-XogA just remove the ...

Comment: removing `...` will say that the expected form of the param is an actual array and not a rest param. i changed the answer to reflect what i mean.

Comment: It works, but I'm receiving an error: when I change to dinamically call console.log(pick<Test>(obj, Object.keys(obj)));
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(keyof Test)[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof Test

Comment: that's due to how `Object.keys` works. it returns you the enumarable string properties as keys in a string array. Also that call would not make a lot of sense, since it would do nothing to the object. (you are calling pick on object while picking all of object keys)

Comment: Got it, and with this code, am I able to get all the informations based on interface ? as I don't know the source I just want to try to map all the Interface. maybe sending all the interface fields. I just start my studies now about this language so some stufs are a little bit harder to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246464/discussion-between-guiherme-souza-and-dean).

Comment: `transformToTest(obj: any)` should not take `any`. It should be `transformToTest(obj: Test)` because you should not be able to pass in an object without `id` and `name`

Comment: i would agree, but went with what OP said. "data from a `any` object"

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree with you, but i need to valid and the create a obj:interface

Comment: But we should tell the OP how to do it right, let the compiler help you, avoid `any` at all costs.

Comment: it will limit it to being usable only for the test type tho. again normally i would agree. in this case i made it more dynamic to be extendable to other types.

Comment: @GuihermeSouza If the incoming object doesn't have the properties, there's no way to do it, so you must ensure that it has `id` and `name`. The compiler will tell you of errors.

Comment: @Dean you didn't. What happens if you pass in `{idx: "ffds", namex: "john"}`? You get an empty object. That's what I'm explaining... What I suggested won't allow you to call it like that...

Comment: @JuanMendes but in another case I will use another interface as Test2 and this interface will not have `id` or `name`

Comment: my bad!!! i read you wanting to change the pick function. totally my bad. you are definitely right. the transform to Test should conform to Test.